# [UICollectionViewCell imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to use collection view and display static images in that, but I get the following error:

> [UICollectionViewCell imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I have configured cell `identifire = Cell`.

Here is my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    SSCollectionViewCell *cell = (SSCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    int imageNumber = indexPath.row % 10;

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%d.jpg",imageNumber]];

    return cell;
}
```

here is the `sscollectionViewCell.h` code

```
@interface SSCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

here is the `SSColletionViewCell.m` code

```
#import "SSCollectionViewCell.h"
@interface SSCollectionViewCell ()

@end


@implementation SSCollectionViewCell
@synthesize imageView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Can any one suggest where i made mistake.?

Comment: Have you registered a XIB file for use with that identifier? If not then the problem is probably that cell is nil.

Comment: You still have not put in the SSColletionViewCell.m code

Comment: If you are not using storyboard or xib for marking the IBOutlet, then you should put a strong reference instead of weak. If you are, then confirm whether the outlet is properly connected to the class.

Comment: I am using storyboard. Sorry abaout .m code. it was skipped. i just updated code above.

Answer (score 10):

Change

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

To

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[SSCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed this in the ViewDidLoad Method

[self.collectionView registerClass:[SSCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

Answer (score 0):

Your cell is still a UICollectionCell and not your custom SSCollectionViewCell, It´s for that does´t know the message (unrecognized selector).

Look in stroryboard, be sure the select the collectionCell, and change it´s class (third tab in right menu), in CustomClass put your now.